Перенос данных из 1С в PostgreSQL
Сейчас данные из 1С сохраняются в Excel файл, после чего запускается ETL, которая грузит таблицу на сервер на базе PSQL. Не могу найти информацию как данные отправлять забирать из 1С. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать.

Поставь PostgREST, в 1с формируешь хттп запрос с данными и они запишутся в таблицу постгреса через него
